# Alternative for deprecated MODE_MULTI_PROCESS in getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider, deprecated, android-syncadapter

Is there any alternative workout for using deprecated MODE_MULTI_PROCESS with getSharedPreferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Tray](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray). It aims directly at solving this issue (and a couple of other issues with shared preferences as well).

Tray actually implements a ContentProvider to store preferences. At present it uses an SQlite database, but AFAIK the design allows other storage backends.

Comment: Thanks..I know that works..I am using a syncadapter and all i want is a flag which would tell if the sync is over or not... regardless of whether the activity is open or not.(That says why a broadcast receiver or syncStatusObserver would nt work).. Using a content provider for just a single flag seems gruesome.. Hope there was something direct

Comment: You were asking for an alternative to `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` with `SharedPreferences`. Tray is one of them. If you want to solve a specific problem you should elaborate on the problem instead of deprecated solutions. For sync adapters there might be better alternatives, depending on what you sync and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yea.. I finally had to go with tray.. Its reliable.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

See at the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), you should use a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) instead.

> This constant was deprecated in API level 23. MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as ContentProvider.